# when i run my derby network server i get this error

Tags: derby

An exception was thrown during network server startup. org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.DRDAServerStarter.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.start(Unknown Source)
    at NewClass1.run(NewClass1.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.DRDAServerStarter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more

Comment: Your question is just error dump, explain your enviroinment clean in your question. What kind of project this is, derby version, maven or ant project, is webapp, using any IDE etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds a lot like [DERBY-3535](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-3535), which was a job that was opened but was closed because nobody could reproduce it and so the root cause was never diagnosed.

The suspicion at the time was that the bug was due to a combination of:

1. Multiple different versions of the Derby jar files on the CLASSPATH
2. The Java security policy in place

Note that you can get multiple versions of Derby quite easily on your system, and some of them may have been installed without your realizing it (e.g., as part of installing the JDK, which has Derby bundled within it, or as part of some application server or other piece of software that has Derby bundled within it).

If you can figure out exactly how to reproduce this problem on a clean system, the Derby community would love to hear about it and fix it. Otherwise, I recommend carefully reviewing your CLASSPATH and looking at which copies of Derby may be present on it, and carefully reviewing your Java security policy and looking at whether it has any tricky parts.

In the short term, if DERBY-3535 is indeed your problem, you can probably work around it by removing the `derby.drda.startNetworkServer=true` configuration from your environment.